# Store file in executable binary

Tags: go

I'm building a command line app that gives audio feedback. I would like to burn the audio file into the executable binary to make it easier to ship it.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) - this will add an extra compile step when your binary files change.